# ORACLE sqlldr LOAD Utility - Date format

Tags: java, database, oracle

I am loading data into TPC-H tables for Oracle using the sqlldr load functionality. For example, the orders.ctl file has the following.

```
load data
INFILE 'orders.tbl'
INTO TABLE ORDERS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
(O_ORDERKEY, O_CUSTKEY, O_ORDERSTATUS, O_TOTALPRICE, O_ORDERDATE DATE 
 'YYYY-MM-DD', O_ORDERPRIORITY, O_CLERK, O_SHIPPRIORITY, O_COMMENT)
```

After loading the data into Orders table, I find that the DATE format is not in 'YYYY-MM-DD' but in the format 'DD-MON-YY'. Why is Oracle not using the format I had mentioned?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

EDIT : Adding java tag as it involves converting the date value passed as string to a java method to convert it back to Date format. See comment to @Justin Cave answer.

Comment: Dates don't have "a format". Any format you see is applied by the SQL client you use to look at the data

Answer (score 0):

A `date` column in Oracle does not have a format.  A string representing a date has a format.  A `date` is always stored in a binary format that is not particularly human readable.  Note that an Oracle `date` also always contains a time component even if your client doesn't display it.

My guess is that you are saying that when you open up SQL*Plus on a machine where you have done a default US-English install of the Oracle client, connect to the database, and do a

```
SELECT o_orderdate
  FROM orders
```

that the date that is displayed is in the format `DD-MON-RR`.  This is because the client needs to convert the `date` to a string representation in order to display it.  If you rely on implicit data type conversion, the client will use your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to do the conversion.  The default for an English language install in the United States is to have an `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` of "DD-MON-RR".  Each session has its own `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` because each user potentially wants to display dates in a different format.

If you want to display the string representation of the date in a particular format, you'd want to use explicit data type conversions using the `to_char` function

```
SELECT to_char( o_orderdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
  FROM orders
```

Comment: The problem I am facing is this. I am passing date values as string to a java method and then converting using java.sql.Date.valueOf(strVal). This method expects the string in YYYY-MM-DD format or it throws an error. Now I do not know which format date is stored in Oracle database so I am not able to use a formatter in java as well. Any way out of this?

Comment: @user2761431: do ***not*** pass dates as strings. Use a `java.sql.Timestamp` and pass it to your preapred statement using `PreparedStatement.setTimestamp()`